# Connect to SharePoint data with JS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have following link that have XML data from SharePoint

```
http://appsrv/pfa/_api/ProjectData/Projects?$select=ProjectName,ProjectStartDate,ProjectPercentCompleted
```

and I have a username & password.

How can I connect to that link with username and password and receive data with JavaScript (outside of SharePoint)?

Comment: I am building a mobile app

Comment: which mobile, windows phone?

Comment: android with ionic framework

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, my suggestion is to develop a provider hosted app. UserName & Password are not need to send in every request. See [this](http://www.codemag.com/article/1501021) how he is doing in SharePoint Online.

I will add more once I am in home.